# When is (true == x) === !!x false?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript has different equality [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

- Equal `==`
- Strict equal `===`

It also has a [logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_%28!%29) `!` and I've tended to think of using a double logical NOT, `!!x`, as basically the same as `true == x`.

However **I know this is not always the case**, e.g. `x = []` because `[]` is *truthy* for `!` but *falsy* for `==`.

So, for which `x`s would `(true == x) === !!x` give false? Alternatively, what is *falsy* by `==` but not `!!` (or vice versa)?

Comment: Loose equality has nothing to do with truthiness.

Comment: Comparing booleans with `==` is generally a bad idea, so you basically should never do `x == true`. If "x" isn't already either `true` or `false` (boolean, that is), then `true` is converted to a number (1) and the comparison proceeds from there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *"So, for which `x`s would `(true == x) === !!x` give `false`?"*

Any `x` where its Boolean conversion is not the same as its conversion by the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3).

---

An example is a string with only whitespace:

```
var x = " ";
```

Its Boolean conversion is `true` *(as is the case with any non-empty string)*, but its `==` comparison is `false` because a string with only white space will be converted to the number `0`, and the `true` value will be converted to the number `1`, and those  values are not equal.

```
x == true; // false
!!x;       // true
```

---

or to show the ultimate values the `==` is comparing:

```
Number(true) == Number(x);
 //      1   ==        0

1 == 0; // false
```

---

and to show the result of `!!x`, it would be equivalent to this:

```
Boolean(x);  // true
```

---

So your original expression could ***crudely*** be seen as the following:

```
   var x = " ";

   (Number(true) == Number(x)) === Boolean(x);
// (         1   ==        0 ) ===        true
//                   ( false ) ===        true

   false === true; // false
```

I say "crudely" because this certainly doesn't capture all the detail of the algorithm linked above, and won't be the same for all values provided to the operands.

To understand how `==` treats its operands, you really need to study the algorithm a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I was basically looking for when [ToBoolean](http://es5.github.com/#x9.2) doesn't match the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3), and now I can read how both of them are defined.

Comment: @PaulS.: You're welcome, and yeah unfortunately there's no simple rule. It comes down to understanding the algorithm, and generally making your life easier by limiting your use of `==`. I don't like to exclude it entirely because there's at least one case where the rule is simple and offers cleaner code.

Comment: just a few more cases to be specific are:
(true == []) === !![] /* false */
(true == {}) === !!{} /* false */

Answer (score -1):

Loose equality has nothing to do with truthiness.

The rules for loose equality basically involve comparing the results of the `.valueOf()` function for each object.
For more details, see the [spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3).